# T-SQL write modified column data to new column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a temporary table that I want to perform some data manipulation on, and then write back to the originating table. However, as a first step I would like to compare the original data side by side with the altered data.

Given the query below, how can I write to the modified data to the a new column in the temporary table so that I can compare side by side? I'm using SQL Server 2008.

---

```
UPDATE #TempCustomControls
SET ConfigValue =
CASE 
    WHEN ConfigValue like '%GetPersonProperty%$PersonID$%'
    THEN 'PersonLogic.GetPersonProperty($PersonID$, ' + RIGHT(ConfigValue, charindex(',', REVERSE(ConfigValue))-1) + ')'

    WHEN ConfigValue like '%GetProfileProperty%$PersonID$%'
    THEN 'PersonLogic.GetPersonProperty($PersonID$, ' + RIGHT(ConfigValue, charindex(',', REVERSE(ConfigValue))-1) + ')'

    WHEN ConfigValue like '%GetProfileProperty%GetJobCreatedByPerson%$JobID$%'
    THEN 'PersonLogic.GetPersonPropertyFromJobID($JobId$, ' + RIGHT(ConfigValue, charindex(',', REVERSE(ConfigValue))-1) + ')'
ELSE
    ConfigValue 
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new column in temp table and update the new column instead of `ConfigValue`.

```
Alter table #TempCustomControls add new_value varchar(100)

UPDATE #TempCustomControls
SET new_value =
CASE 
    WHEN ConfigValue like '%GetPersonProperty%$PersonID$%'
    THEN 'PersonLogic.GetPersonProperty($PersonID$, ' + RIGHT(ConfigValue, charindex(',', REVERSE(ConfigValue))-1) + ')'

    WHEN ConfigValue like '%GetProfileProperty%$PersonID$%'
    THEN 'PersonLogic.GetPersonProperty($PersonID$, ' + RIGHT(ConfigValue, charindex(',', REVERSE(ConfigValue))-1) + ')'

    WHEN ConfigValue like '%GetProfileProperty%GetJobCreatedByPerson%$JobID$%'
    THEN 'PersonLogic.GetPersonPropertyFromJobID($JobId$, ' + RIGHT(ConfigValue, charindex(',', REVERSE(ConfigValue))-1) + ')'
ELSE
    ConfigValue 
END
```

To check `select` both the columns

```
Select ConfigValue,new_value 
From #TempCustomControls
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the quick reply.